# Thumbnail creation. On the fly or create small image?

Tags: android, performance

The question regarding thumbnail creation seems to get asked a great deal, and each time there seems to be a great many different solutions proposed.  From my experience none of the supplied answers are actually sufficient and all seem to have their own flaws.

**a)**  Memory issues when re-sizing

**b)**  Performance issues / slow to render

I therefore wanted to post a question regarding a very common functional requirement that I am hoping someone can assist with.

'User generates a report using activity and takes associated photo using internal camera.  The report along with the image path is saved to SQLLite database.   User wants to view reports in a scrollable list view at some point in the future.  Number of reports could be 1..100'

So given these requirements the questions I have are as follows

1)  Given that to data I have not found a reliable / performent / memory optimised way of resizing full size images at run time to a given thumbnail, should I create a smaller image at image capture time?

2)  If you need to display many items in a ListView should you use paging or should it be possible to display a 100 items in one ListView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding number 2: What you could do is load a subset first (say the first 30, depending on your listview item size), and load the rest asynchronously and append them to your adapter. This will decrease the loading time of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

1/ Why do you want to reinvent the wheel :) There are libraries that already do for you and do it well. See picasso or AQuery for instance (there are other libraries too).

Basically, they have a thumbnail cache somewhere on the SDcard/internal memory to keep last N requested thumbnails.

I don't know if you are keeping the image data within the database, in which case you may have to adapt one of those libraries to load the image data from the DB and not from a file as it is usually the case.

2/ Why do you want to reinvent the wheel :) There are libraries that already do for you and do it well. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless for instance (and google for more)